# "uncaught throw :async" when using async_sinatra with Rails EventMachine and Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, eventmachine, thin

I'm trying to setup my environment for having both rails, EventMachine and async_sinatra play together and I guess I have something setup wrong because I get an error "uncaught throw :async".

This is my what I have in my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'async_sinatra'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'rack-fiber_pool',  :require => 'rack/fiber_pool'
gem 'thin'
```

This is the config.ru:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
use Rack::FiberPool
run Longpoll::Application
```

This what I have in my routes.rb file:

```
match '/longpoll', :to => LongPoll
```

and this is my long_poll.rb file:

```
class LongPoll < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async

  aget '/longpoll' do
    body 'Hello world!'
  end
end
```

Any ideas what am I missing for this setup to work?

**EDIT:**

I figured out that working without rack-fiber_pool fixes things.
Can anyone confirm whether they can work together or not?

Another example which gives the same error basic.ru:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rackup -Ilib:../lib -s thin
require 'sinatra/async'
require 'rack/fiber_pool'

class AsyncTest < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Async
  use Rack::FiberPool

  enable :show_exceptions

  aget '/' do
    body "hello async"
  end
end

run AsyncTest.new
```

Answer (score 2):

if have seen this error when using `webrick`, switching to `thin` solved it.
therefore i can not directly confirm your assumption, but i guess using `webrick` as well as `rack-fiber_pool` might break.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra/async"

class AsyncTest < Sinatra::Base
  set :server, :thin

  register Sinatra::Async

  aget '/' do
    body "hello async"
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

the code above works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

IMO they are mutually exclusive.

rack-fiber-pool takes care of calling the `async.callback` with the results of the fiber. It also takes care of doing a `throw :async` to tell thin to keep the connection open. async_sinatra also takes care of the exact same things. It calls `async.callback` when you call `body {}`. and also does a `throw :async` thinking it has to tell thin to keep the connection open. This is the issue you are seeing. async_sinatra is throwing :async and rack-fiber-pool is catching it and thinking it was an actual error.

You can look at async_sinatra throwing here: https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/async.rb#L69

and rack-fiber-pool catching here: https://github.com/mperham/rack-fiber_pool/blob/master/lib/rack/fiber_pool.rb#L24

You can also check out sinatra_synchrony if you want the best of both.